# How can I use SQLite3 v3.7 API on Ubuntu?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I want to backup a `sqlite3` database `existing_db.db` into an in-memory database `:memory:` using [`sqlite3.Connection.backup()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.backup)? `backup()` is available with SQLite 3.6.11 or higher. New in version 3.7. If I run the follwing code

```
import sqlite3

source = sqlite3.connect('existing_db.db')
dest = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
source.backup(dest)
```

I get the error `AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'backup'`. How can I make `backup()` work? My setup is Ubuntu 18.04.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 18:26:19) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.22.0'
```

Comment: That's version 3.7 of *python*, not *sqlite*. Ubuntu 18.04 uses Python 3.6, so you'll have to figure out how to upgrade that.

Comment: Ah ***!! Right. Thx.

Comment: The documentation could be worded better.